# FFmpeg for marking time video based on a reference date

Tags: ffmpeg, timestamp, overlay

I am trying to mark a timestamp in a video using `drawtext` filter. 
FFmpeg easily marks timestamps based on `localtime`, `gmtime` or even `PTS`. However, I want to assign a reference time (start time) for the timestamp in order to represent the time the video was **recorded** (not encoded).

Reading the documentation, I found that option `basetime` can be used for this purpose. However it seems that is not working or I am missing something.

The command line I am using is:

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -filter_complex drawtext="fontfile=/tmp/UbuntuMono-B.ttf: fontsize=36: fontcolor=yellow: box=1: boxcolor=black@0.4: text='Wall Clock Time\: %{gmtime\:%Y-%m-%d %T}': basetime=1456007118" output.mp4
```

By using `basetime=1456007118`, it was expected the start time was set to '02/20/2016 20:25:18' since 1456007118 is the UTC time for that time and date:

```
date -d '02/20/2016 20:25:18' +"%s" # format MM/DD/AAAA hh:mm:ss
1456007118
```

However, no error is issued by FFmpeg and the video is marked with current GMT, ignoring `basetime` option.

Any hint?
Thanks.

Complete information about FFmpeg version and output is:

```
ffmpeg -y -i /home/denio/Videos/Interstellar_2014_Trailer_4_5.1-1080p-HDTN.mp4 -filter_complex drawtext="fontfile=/tmp/UbuntuMono-B.ttf: fontsize=36: fontcolor=yellow: box=1: boxcolor=black@0.4: text='Wall Clock Time\: %{gmtime\:%Y-%m-%d %T}': basetime=1470226363" /tmp/x.mp4 
ffmpeg version 3.1.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.3.1 (Ubuntu 5.3.1-14ubuntu2.1) 20160413
  configuration: --enable-libxavs --enable-bzlib --enable-libfaac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib --enable-x11grab --enable-static --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-version3 --disable-ffserver --enable-libgsm --enable-librtmp --enable-libvpx --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopenjpeg
  libavutil      55. 28.100 / 55. 28.100
  libavcodec     57. 48.101 / 57. 48.101
  libavformat    57. 41.100 / 57. 41.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 47.100 /  6. 47.100
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
...
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see the `basetime` in the source code, but not in the web documentation, so not sure how it's supposed to work.

You can instead use the `pts` function.

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=/tmp/UbuntuMono-B.ttf:
                            fontsize=36:fontcolor=yellow:
                            box=1:boxcolor=black@0.4:
                            text='Wall Clock Time\: %{pts\:gmtime\:1456007118}'"
   output.mp4
```

You may need to reset PTS (`setpts=PTS-STARTPTS`) before the drawtext.

Comment: Yes, it works very fine. I read documentation at [https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext-1] an I think I could never conclude this based on it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Gyan what if i want to use custom date time ex: i want 02-12-2019 04:25:12 so it will start counting from 12

Comment: How can I scale the frame rate? I can't figure out how to multiply the `%{pts\:gmtime\:1456007118}` by a constant to get the value I need.

Comment: yes @YamielSerrano