# FFMPEG: Create timestamp based on actual creation time

Tags: ffmpeg

**Desired outcome**

Add overlay with timestamp for each frame of a video based on the original creation time for the video. E.g. starting at 2022-03-26T15:51:49.000000Z and a second later in the video present 2022-03-26T15:51.50.000000Z

**Approach**

Creation_time stored in the file already, e.g. when running `ffmpeg -i input.mov"` it presents `creation_time   : 2022-03-26T15:51:49.000000Z`.

Adding overlay with timestamp to video:
`ffmpeg -i input.mov -filter_complex "drawtext=text='%{pts\:gmtime\:1507046400\:%d-%m-%Y %T}': x=100 : y=100: box=1" -c:a copy output.mp4`

**Challenge/ help needed**

Need to replace the `gmtime\:1507046400` with the actual `creation_time`. How does one do it?

**Sources**

- Overlay: https://superuser.com/questions/1013753/how-can-i-overlay-the-captured-timestamp-onto-a-video-using-ffmpeg-in-yyyy-mm-dd
- Creation_time:
  [FFMPEG - Get creation and/or modification date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31541489/ffmpeg-get-creation-and-or-modification-date)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38747518/ffmpeg-for-marking-time-video-based-on-a-reference-date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link I suggested is for a fixed datetime.
For a rolling time use a time offset.
If I pick an arbitary date and time as 2022/2/28 at 12:02:03, calculate the number of seconds for the offset, in this instance 12 x 60 x 60 plus 2 x 60 plus 3 equals 43323.
We fix the date as text, then use the offset for the time.

```
ffmpeg -i some.mp4 -filter_complex  "[0:v]drawtext=text='2022 02 28 %{pts\:hms\:43323}':x=(w-text_w)/2:y=10:font='Noto mono':fontsize=40:alpha=0.5:box=1:boxborderw=4 [vid]" -map [vid] -map 0:a -f matroska - | ffplay -autoexit -i -
```

[image]

For a video running past midnight, you'll need a variation on that theme.

```
ffmpeg -i some.mp4 -filter_complex  "[0:v]drawtext=text='%{pts\:gmtime\:1646092780}':x=(w-text_w)/2:y=10:font='Noto mono':fontsize=40:alpha=0.5:box=1:boxborderw=4 [vid]" -map [vid] -map 0:a -f matroska - | ffplay -autoexit -i -
```

Here the offset is calculated as elapsed seconds since the Unix epoch time (01/01/1970 00:00:00)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks - this is brilliant and I really appreciate that you thought about the past midnight aspect as well.

Do you know a way to obtain the variable of creation_time? If necessary I can run this through a script (e.g. PHP) - but would love to obtain the creation time dynamically and then run your terminal command.

Comment: @PederWessel See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31541489/ffmpeg-get-creation-and-or-modification-date    -    but be aware that not all media has metatags or a full set of metatags, so have a backup plan, if you don't find a creation date.

Comment: Thanks - works like a beauty! Working on backup plan.

Again thank you!